# Prevent Default Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent the enter button when pressed on an input field that is within form tags to submit and and refresh the page. Instead I want to load an AJAX file. Now I know if I got rid of the form tags then this would work and I wouldn't even need the `e.preventDefault();` tags. What am I missing here? Code is below.

```
$('#input_field').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        e.preventDefault();
            $('#insert_ajax_file').load('load_file.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyup event is fired after the default event.
Use keydown

```
$('#input_field').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `e.preventDefault` as you are passing event object as `e` as an arg.

See below,

```
$('#input_field').bind('keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode==13){
      e.preventDefault(); //<== Changed to e
        $('#insert_ajax_file').load('load_file.php');
   }
   //..
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the 'click' event instead of 'keyup':

```
$('#input_field').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do whatever you want here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzkaN/

**EDIT**: Sorry, misread your question.

Use `keypress` instead of `keyup` then.
http://jsfiddle.net/rzkaN/1/

Comment: You're right. Had to give the answer to Liviu though since he beat you by a minute. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, but... I don't know how you accepted his answer because `keydown` is fired after `keypress` (at least in Firefox) and after the default event for some reason... http://jsfiddle.net/rzkaN/2/

Answer (score 0):

you pass an 'e' at your function, but do a preventDefault on 'event'

Working:

```
$('#input_field').bind('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==13){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#insert_ajax_file').load('load_file.php');
  }
});
```

Comment: its better to prevent the submit  $("form").submit(function() rather than the keyup event

Comment: Still does not work or at least how I wrote it.  $("form").submit(function(e) { if(e.keyCode==13){ e.preventDefault();
$('#insert_ajax_file').load('load_file.php');
}});

Comment: without the if keyCode : $('form').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('#insert_ajax_file').load('load_file.php'); });